# How to loop through similar named xml items php

Tags: php, xml

I am working with an XML feed and inside the object, it lists multiple items and in it has pictures I want to access. I can't figure out how to loop through each yachtPic without having to manually add the number in and for some feeds the pic numbers will be higher or lower. I know I might have to do something with strpos() function but I am not sure how that works with trying to access an xml object.

The xml I used to print_r the simple xml object: https://pastebin.com/vk1FW1i8

```
 SimpleXMLElement Object
 (
     [yacht] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
            [yachtId] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtLogo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtType] => Cat
        [yachtLength] => 77
        [yachtPowerCat] => N
        [sizeFeet] => 77.0 Ft
        [sizeMeter] => 23.0 m
        [yachtBeam] => 34
        [yachtDraft] => 6
        [yachtUnits] => Feet
        [yachtPax] => 10
        [yachtCabins] => 5
        [yachtKing] => 3
        [yachtQueen] => 2
        [yachtSingleCabins] => 0
        [yachtDoubleCabins] => 0
        [yachtTwinCabins] => 0
        [yachtPullmanCabins] => 0
        [yachtRefit] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtHelipad] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtJacuzzi] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtAc] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPrefPickup] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtOtherPickup] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtTurnAround] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtYearBuilt] => 2016
        [yachtBuilder] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtBrokerWeb] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtUserWeb] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtVideo] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

            )

        [yachtCruiseSpeed] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMaxSpeed] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtAccommodations] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtHighPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtLowPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPriceDetails] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

            )

        [yachtTermsType] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtVcrDvd] => Yes
        [yachtSalonStereo] => Yes
        [yachtNumDvd] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtNumCds] => Yes
        [yachtBoardGames] => Yes
        [yachtNumBooks] => 20
        [yachtCamCorder] => No
        [yachtNumDineIn] => 8
        [yachtSunAwning] => Yes
        [yachtHammock] => No
        [yachtWindScoops] => No
        [yachtDeckShower] => Yes
        [yachtBimini] => Yes
        [yachtSpecialDiets] => Yes
        [yachtKosher] => No
        [yachtBBQ] => Yes
        [yachtGayCharters] => Yes
        [yachtNudeCharters] => No
        [yachtHairDryer] => Yes
        [yachtNumHatch] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtGuestSmoke] => Aft Deck
        [yachtGuestPet] => No
        [yachtChildrenAllowed] => Yes
        [yachtMinChildAge] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtGenerator] => 18 kw
        [yachtEngines] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtFuel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtInverter] => Yes
        [yachtVoltages] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtWaterMaker] => Yes
        [yachtWaterCapacity] => 75 gallons
        [yachtIceMaker] => Yes
        [yachtDinghy] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDinghyHp] => 70
        [yachtDinghyPax] => 10
        [yachtAdultWSkis] => No
        [yachtKidsSkis] => No
        [yachtJetSkis] => No
        [yachtWaveRun] => No
        [yachtKneeBoard] => Yes
        [yachtStandUpPaddle] => 0
        [yachtWindSurf] => No
        [yachtGearSnorkel] => 10
        [yachtTube] => Yes
        [yachtScurfer] => No
        [yachtWakeBoard] => Yes
        [yacht1ManKayak] => 2
        [yacht2ManKayak] => No
        [yachtFloatMats] => Yes
        [yachtSwimPlatform] => Yes
        [yachtBoardingLadder] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDinghySailing] => No
        [yachtGamesBeach] => Yes
        [yachtFishingGear] => Yes
        [yachtFishGearType] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtNumFishRods] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtUnderWaterCam] => Yes
        [yachtUnderWaterVideo] => 0
        [yachtGreenMakeWater] => Yes
        [yachtGreenReuseBottle] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtGreenOther] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtScubaOnboard] => Onboard
        [yachtResortCourse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtFullCourse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtLicenseInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCompressor] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtNumDiveTanks] => 0
        [yachtNumBCS] => 0
        [yachtNumRegs] => 0
        [yachtNumWetSuits] => 0
        [yachtNumWeights] => 0
        [yachtNumDivers] => 0
        [yachtNumDives] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtNumNightDives] => 0
        [yachtNumDiveLights] => 1
        [yachtDiveInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDiveCosts] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic11] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc11] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic13] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc13] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic14] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc14] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic15] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc15] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic16] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc16] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic17] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc17] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic18] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc18] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic19] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDesc19] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtLayout] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtFullEbrochure] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtFullRates] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtOtherToys] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtOtherEntertain] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCommunicate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtSummerArea] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtWinterArea] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtShowers] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtWashBasins] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtHeads] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtElectricHeads] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic2Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic3Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic4Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic5Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic6Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic7Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic8Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic9Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic10Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic11Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic12Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic13Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic14Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic15Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic16Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic17Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic18Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPic19Large] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtSampleMenu] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMenu1Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMenu2Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMenu3Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMenu4Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMenu5Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMenu6Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMenu7Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMenu8Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMenu9Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMenu10Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew] => 3
        [yachtCrewSmoke] => No
        [yachtCrewPets] => No
        [yachtCrewPetType] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCaptainName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCaptainNation] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCaptainBorn] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCaptainLic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCaptainYrSail] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCaptainYrChart] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCaptainLang] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrewName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrewNation] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrewLic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrewYrSail] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrewYrChart] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrewLang] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrewProfile] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrewPhoto] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew1Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew2Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew3Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew4Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew5Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew6Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew7Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew8Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew9Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew10Pic] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew1Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew2Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew3Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew4Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew5Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew6Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew7Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew8Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew9Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew10Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew1Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew2Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew3Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew4Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew5Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew6Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew7Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew8Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew9Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCrew10Title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtFlag] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtHomePort] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtWBasePort] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtRig] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtGrossTons] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtAcNight] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtAcSurCharge] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtTubs] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtLocationDetails] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtTerms] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCaptOnly] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtSpecialCon] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtContracts] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtConsumptionUnits] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtRange] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPermit] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtLicense] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtMca] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtDeepSeaFish] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtSatTv] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtIpod] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtSailInstruct] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtInternet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtBrokerNotes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtInsCompany] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtPolicy] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtLiability] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtEffectiveDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtContractName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtCoverageAreas] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtInsFlag] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtInsHomeport] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtRegNum] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtConPhone1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtConPhone2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtConPhone3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtConFax] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtWaveConEmail] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtConOther] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtManager] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtManagerName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtManagerPhone] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtManagerToll] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [yachtManagerEmail] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

      )

  )
```

Code I am trying to work with

```
$xml_ebrochure = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml_ebrochure as $value_ebrochure) {

    $name = 'yachtPic';
    foreach ($value_ebrochure as $key) {
      if (strpos($key, $name) > 0) {
        echo $key;
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a description will always follow a picture, you can use [**modulo**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to work out whether the item currently being looped over is a picture or the corresponding description:

```
$i = 0; // Set up a counter
foreach ($xml_ebrochure as $value_ebrochure) {
    if ($value_ebrochure[$i] % 2 === 0) {
        // You've got a picture
        $name = 'yachtPic';
    } else {
        // You've got the description
    }
    $i++; // Increment the counter
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late comment I actually updated my post to reflect the xml object I am using exactly since that code doesn't seem to be working because I have to access the object.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the tag is already present in the first loop, you only need to specify you want to use it:

```
$xml_ebrochure = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml_ebrochure as $key => $value_ebrochure) { // $key will contain the tag name
    $name = 'yachtPic';
      if (strpos($key, $name) !== false) {
        echo $key.": ".$value_ebrochure;
    }

}
```

Note that the condition to check if the `$name` is present is a little different. You need to compare the result of `strpos()` with `false` with a [strict comparison](https://www.copterlabs.com/strict-vs-loose-comparisons-in-php/), in this case because since the string matches completely it will return `0` (the match starts in the first position), and you had a `>` comparison.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/u1YkW)

Comment: Sorry for late response, I just updated the post to reflect the xml object I am using. I think it might affect the result of your code since it's not working fo rme.

Comment: It's impossible to do further testing with the dump you've attached. Post the actual XML source in order to see what's up. Did you try tinkering with this at all? Try this though: `foreach ($xml_ebrochure->yacht as $key => $value_ebrochure) {`

Comment: here is the pastebin of the raw xml: https://pastebin.com/vk1FW1i8 I am accessing the xml through a server so I need to be able to check each yacht->yachtPic(with different numbers) from hundreds of other xml documents. I have tried your solution and others but I still am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you need `yactPic`s only, you probably want to use XPath to fetch them:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<root>
    <yachtPic1>.p1.</yachtPic1>
    <yachtDesc1>.d1.</yachtDesc1>
    <yachtPic2>.p2.</yachtPic2>
    <yachtDesc2>.d2.</yachtDesc2>
    <yachtPic3>.p3.</yachtPic3>
    <yachtDesc3>.v3.</yachtDesc3>
</root>';

$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$res = $root->xpath('*[starts-with(local-name(), "yachtPic")]');

$pics = [];

foreach ($res as $elem) {
    $pics[] = $elem->__toString();
}

var_dump($pics);
```

Will output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) ".p1."
  [1] =>
  string(4) ".p2."
  [2] =>
  string(4) ".p3."
}
```

if you need pictures and descriptions combined:

```php
$xml = '...';

$root = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$pics = [];
foreach ($root->xpath('*[starts-with(local-name(), "yachtPic")]') as $elem) {
    $picDescTagName = preg_replace('/Pic(\d+)$/', 'Desc$1', $elem->getName());
    $pics[$picDescTagName]['pic'] = $elem->__toString();
}
unset($elem, $picDescTagName);

foreach ($root->xpath('*[starts-with(local-name(), "yachtDesc")]') as $elem) {
    $picDescTagName = $elem->getName();
    $pics[$picDescTagName]['desc'] = $elem->__toString();
}
unset($elem, $picDescTagName);

$pics = array_values($pics);
print_r($pics);
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pic] => .p1.
            [desc] => .d1.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pic] => .p2.
            [desc] => .d2.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pic] => .p3.
            [desc] => .v3.
        )

)
```

Comment: I updated my post since the yacht pics I am grabbing are not the root I have to access them with in an object so I am not sure how to change what you have to that.